# How to write a Python lexical analyser?

Tags: python, c, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to write a C module to lexically analyse Python code. How can I do it?

Comment: Cut the net speak, and can you state your problem in a much more specific way?

Comment: (To others confused by Xavier's comment, it is against the first revision of the question. The more recent edit is much clearer.)

Answer (score 10):

The complete, detailed specification for doing lexical analysis of Python code is [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=lexical).

As you can see, there are a lot of cases you need to cover.  One help is that you will always be able to check most easily if your C-implemented lexical analyzer is correct for a given Python fragment: it will have to return exactly what the Python-implemented module [tokenize](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/tokenize.html?highlight=token#module-tokenize) in Python's standard library does.

As you can see in tokenize's [sources](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/tokenize.py?annotate=75432), it's several hundred lines of Python, so you can easily extrapolate to needing thousands of lines of C -- definitely *not* a weekend project;-)

Of course, as a starting point, you can fork Python's own [Parser/tokenizer.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Parser/tokenizer.c?annotate=81029) -- that's less than 2000 lines (amazingly short for what it does!), but in good part because it's relying on quite a few other bits and pieces from Python's runtime (if your implementation needs to be stand-alone you'll therefore need to reproduce those).

If you're a very experienced programmer with strong understanding of the Python's codebase, and can just sprint on this for all your waking hours, you *might* make it in a week or so. Under normal circumstances, I'd say expecting a month of work would be a bit optimistic.  What's your deadline?

Comment: I'd also ask why you want to do this in C rather than in Python.